# Benefit of wrapping List<T> into class TList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, model

The company I work for has been doing some arguably odd things in their source code.

One of these things I can't wrap my head around (no pun intended) is the benefit of wrapping a `List<T>` in a `class TList`.

Example

```
public class ThingModel
{
    //model properties
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ThingModelList : List<ThingModel>
{
    //this is just an empty wrapper, no code is in here in our source
}
```

in the methods that use a list of ThingModel you would do
`ThingModelList = new ThingModelList();` rather than `List<ThingModel> = new List<ThingModel>();`

I don't see the benefit of doing this, and it's confused me multiple times (especially with longer names). Maybe someone could give me some insight into the benefits?

Comment: Cannot see any benefit in the case you have shown (i.e where it contains no code), but it can be useful in some scenarios. For example `SelectList` is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, and it provides constructors that allow you to generate `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` for use in dropdownlists

Comment: The only thing I would see could be the ability to add, expand or change the behaviour of the class afterwards, even when its been used in a lot of places.

Comment: I see where you're coming from, but in this case they just use it as a different way to write List<Foo> as FooList. So I guess it has no benifits?

Comment: I've done it once so my collection can implement ITypedList, which was a requirement for a third party library.

Comment: A reason could be brevity. Generic class definitions can be lengthy. Recently I had to work with an array of `List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`. I inherited from `List` so that I can work with a `Bucket[]` instead: `private class Bucket : List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> { }`